# get last 5 records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where the exact last 5 records are being fetched but i am unable to understand how it is working can anyone please help me in understanding it.

```
Select * from EMP a
where 5 > (select count(*) from EMP b where a.rowid < b.rowid );
```

Comment: If I were to try simplify this approach I would probably choose an inner join. Assuming yout query is correct, I am assuming this approach makes similar operations to join operation. However simple answer below using DESC would be preferable.

Comment: A little [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/9WpIM8Aq) with some sample data for this query.

Answer (score 3):

That query presumes that ROWIDs are sequential and represent order in which rows have been entered into a table. That doesn't have to be true. ROWIDs can change - for example, if you export the table (using Data Pump Export) and import it back. Therefore, it is pure luck you got correct result.

You should have a column which represents real order; for example, a column whose source is a sequence, ID which is generated automatically as *identity column*, a timestamp or something similar.

Then you'd be able to return rows that were last inserted. For example, based on Scott's `EMP` table & presuming that `empno` is sequential:

```
SQL> select empno, ename from emp order by empno;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER   5      --> these rows are the ones we want to get 
      7876 ADAMS    4
      7900 JAMES    3
      7902 FORD     2
      7934 MILLER   1
 
14 rows selected.
```

If you apply the row_number analytic function, you get

```
SQL> select empno, ename,
  2            row_number() over (order by empno desc) rn
  3     from emp
  4  order by empno;

     EMPNO ENAME              RN
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH              14
      7499 ALLEN              13
      7521 WARD               12
      7566 JONES              11
      7654 MARTIN             10
      7698 BLAKE               9
      7782 CLARK               8
      7788 SCOTT               7
      7839 KING                6
      7844 TURNER              5       --> see #5 here?
      7876 ADAMS               4
      7900 JAMES               3
      7902 FORD                2
      7934 MILLER              1

14 rows selected.
```

Then you'd use such a subquery:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select empno, ename,
  3            row_number() over (order by empno desc) rn
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select empno, ename
  7  from temp
  8  where rn <= 5
  9  order by rn;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7934 MILLER
      7902 FORD
      7900 JAMES
      7876 ADAMS
      7844 TURNER

SQL>
```

Or

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select empno, ename
  3        from emp
  4        order by empno desc
  5       )
  6  fetch first 5 rows only;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7934 MILLER
      7902 FORD
      7900 JAMES
      7876 ADAMS
      7844 TURNER

SQL>
```

Or

```
select * 
from (select empno, ename, rownum rn
      from emp
      order by empno desc
     )
where rn <= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

> i am unable to understand how it is working

Your current query:

```
Select * from EMP a
where 5 > (select count(*) from EMP b where a.rowid < b.rowid );
```

is using a correlated subquery to count how many rows in the same table have a 'lower' rowid value.

You can use the same correlated subquery to see the count for each row in the table:

```
select a.*, 
  (select count(*) from EMP b where a.rowid < b.rowid ) as num_with_higher_rowid
from EMP a;
```

If you had a table with 10 rows of data then that might look like:

| ID | NUM_WITH_HIGHER_ROWID |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 9 |
| 53 | 8 |
| 55 | 7 |
| 57 | 6 |
| 59 | 5 |
| 61 | 4 |
| 63 | 3 |
| 65 | 2 |
| 67 | 1 |
| 69 | 0 |

The last row created is ID 69, and so that has the highest rowid (let's pretend for now - see @Littlefoot's answer for why this isn't necessarily or reliably true), which means there are zero rows with a higher rowid. For the penultimate rowid there is one row with a higher rowid, and so on.

Your query is comparing those counts with the number 5, so let's see what that comparison would show for each row and its count:

```
select a.*, 
  (select count(*) from EMP b where a.rowid < b.rowid ) as num_with_higher_rowid,
  case
    when (select count(*) from EMP b where a.rowid < b.rowid ) < 5 then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
  end as less_than_5_higher
from EMP a;
```

| ID | NUM_WITH_HIGHER_ROWID | LESS_THAN_5_HIGHER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 9 | No |
| 53 | 8 | No |
| 55 | 7 | No |
| 57 | 6 | No |
| 59 | 5 | No |
| 61 | 4 | Yes |
| 63 | 3 | Yes |
| 65 | 2 | Yes |
| 67 | 1 | Yes |
| 69 | 0 | Yes |

Your query is essentially filtering that result to only pick the rows that get 'Yes', by comparing the count value with the fixed number 5, to give:

| ID |
| --- |
| 61 |
| 63 |
| 65 |
| 67 |
| 69 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9HLTxW9x)

However, as explained elsewhere, this is not a reliable way to find the most recently created rows, and also doesn't seem very efficient. Use one of the other suggested methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the basics;

```
SELECT * FROM EMP a ORDER BY a.rowid DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: But will this select "last 5 records"?   Answer: That depends on how **last** is defined, which is not clear from the question, and from this answer.

Comment: Very true. I overlooked that perspective. Thank you for your comment :)